# Comparas los valores de dos diccionarios

Tags: python, lista, python-3.7, diccionarios, comparaciones

Tengo esto:

```
x = {"mots": [["Le","gouvernement"],["gouvernement","pousse"]]}
y = {"mots": [["Quatre","blessés"],["blessés","collision"],["gouvernement","pousse"]]}
```

Lo que deseo es obtener los valores que coinciden, en este caso quisiera como salida

```
"gouvernement","pousse"
```

Intente:

```
egal = {k: x[k] for k in x if k in y and x[k] == y[k]}
```

Evidentemente no funciona, he intentado otros metodos pero o me dice que no es valido para el diccionario o que no es valido para las listas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres comparar una misma llave en dos diccionarios, la solución es:

```
lista = [n for n in x['mots'] if n in y['mots']]
```

La expresión `x['mots']` produce una lista de listas. Al recorrerla con `for`, obtengo una sublista a la vez. Está sublista (`n`) la incluyo en la salida sólo si está también entre los elementos de y[`mots`].

Si las llaves no son conocidas, la solución será primero iterar sobre las llaves de `x` aplicando el código anterior:

```
x = {"mots": [["Le","gouvernement"],["gouvernement","pousse"]]}
y = {"mots": [["Quatre","blessés"],["blessés","collision"],["gouvernement","pousse"]]}

lista = []
for key in x.keys():
    lista.extend([n for n in x[key] if n in y[key]])
print(lista)
```

produce

```
[['gouvernement', 'pousse']]
```

Comment: De la misma manera al estilo de programación funcional: lista = list(filter(lambda v: v in x["mots"], y["mots"])). Y en el caso de que no sepamos el key: list(map(lambda key: list(filter(lambda v: v in x[key], y[key]))[0], y))